# Chrome opens on running flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, wsl-2

I'm developing with FLutter on a WSL2 Debian machine. I didn't want to install Chrome on it, so I set CHROME_EXECUTABLE to the path of the Windows installation of Chrome.

Every time I run `flutter doctor`, Chrome launches and I have to close it.

It's just a minor annoyance, I know.
How can I stop this behaviour?